# Swig setter for an object member that has no default constructor

Tags: python, c++, swig

Swig generates wrapper code for a object member that has not default constructor.

Code to wrap:

```
class Foo {
   public:
   Foo (int i);
};

Class Bar {
   public:
   Bar(int i):foo(i) 
   {
    ...
   }
   Foo foo;
};
```

Swig Setter generated:

```
SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_Bar_foo_set(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) {
  PyObject *resultobj = 0;
  Bar *arg1 = (Bar *) 0 ;
  Foo arg2 ; // -> swig generates a call to a non existing default constructor

  ...
```

Then, if a try to compile the wrapper, I get an error since the default contructor does not exist:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo::Foo()’
```

Please note, the same approach is done for the getter generation.

How can I tell swig to generate a setter that accepts Foo* or Foo&?

Thanks,
Pablo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWIG fundamentally supports this just fine, in fact I can't actually reproduce what you've seen with the code you showed. For example, this all works:

```
%module test

%inline %{
class Foo {
   public:
   Foo (int i) {}
};

class Bar {
   public:
   Bar(int i):foo(i)
   {
   }
   Foo foo;
};
%}
```

When compiled and run with SWIG 3.0.2 (which is pretty old these days!) lets me run this Python code:

```
import test

f=test.Foo(0)

b=test.Bar(0)
b.foo=f
print('Well that all worked ok')
```

The reason this can work, even in the more general cases, is because of a [feature known as the "Fulton Transform"](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus_nn19). In essence this is intended to work around a lack of copy constructor by wrapping it inside another object instead. (Although in the specific instance you've shown it's not actually needed even).

Anyway, although this should apply automatically there are a few cases were it can't won't. Fortunately though you can force this on even when it doesn't work automatically, using `%feature`

All you need to do is include, within your .i file, somewhere before first declaration/definition of a type without a copy ctor the following:

```
%feature("valuewrapper") Foo;
```

And that's it.